# Using Socket IO with Express JS

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

(Not familiar with node.)

I generated my `express` js app using the `express-generator`

so the file structure looks like this

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

I wanted to implement socket io. so on file `bin/www`

I added this code below `server.listen(port);`

```
server.listen(port);
/**
 * Socket IO
 */
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  console.log('a user connected');
  console.log(socket.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
    console.log(socket.id);
  });

});
```

every time a client connect, it logs

> a user connected

now I want to post an update to a specific user using their socket.id

on routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var io      = require('socket.io');

/* GET home page. */
router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next)
    {
        res.send('Nothing to do here');
    })
    .post(function(req, res, next)
        {
            var socketid = req.param('socketid');
            io.broadcast.to(id).emit('message', "Hello World");
        }
    );

module.exports = router;
```

Now Every time I post. I get an error

```
Cannot read property 'to' of undefined
```

it seems that I got a wrong io.

should I require also the server inside my index.js?

or how can I use the one io var declared in www? is this possible? just use the existing objects already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `Cannot read property 'to' of undefined`, because you have not defined `io` in `routes\index.js` file and you don't have reference to `io` in `bin/www`.

You can resolve the issue by passing the newly `io` object to the routes file.
e.g.

**bin/www**

```
server.listen(port);
/**
  * Socket IO
*/
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//remove same lines from app.js
var routes = require('./router/index.js')(io);
app.use('/', routes)

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
   console.log(socket.id);

   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
      console.log(socket.id);
   });
});
```

**router/index.js**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
   var express = require('express');
   var router  = express.Router();

   /* GET home page. */
   router.route('/').get(function(req, res, next){
      res.send('Nothing to do here');
   }).post(function(req, res, next){
        var socketid = req.param('socketid');
        io.broadcast.to(id).emit('message', "Hello World");
   });
   return router;
}
```

Let me know, if it doesn't work.